# Action group of set. Theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to prove that: If $G$ is an action group of set $A$ and $x\in A$ then $G_x$ is a subgroup of group $G$.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: is $G_x$ the orbit of the element $x$ or the stabiliser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving the stabilizer is a subgroup of the group to prove the Orbit-Stabiliser theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265963/proving-the-stabilizer-is-a-subgroup-of-the-group-to-prove-the-orbit-stabiliser)

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa Personally, I would write the orbit as $Gx$, being consistent with a lot of other notation (like cosets, for instance).

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa Apart from standardness of the notations $G_x$ versus $Gx$, another reason for assuming $G_x$ means the stabilizer is that the orbit is usually not even a subset of $G$ (let alone a subgroup).

Comment: $G_x$ is completely standard notation for the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$ so I don't know why so many people are querying this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I assume $G_x$ is the stabiliser of $x$*

Let $a,b\in G_x$. Now if for all $a,b\in G_x$ we have $ab^{-1}\in G_x$ then $G_x$ is a subgroup, since $G_x$ is nonempty. Now since $a,b\in G_x$ we have
$$
ax=x\qquad bx=x\Rightarrow x=b^{-1}x
$$
so
$$
x=ax=a(b^{-1}x)=(ab^{-1})x\Rightarrow ab^{-1}\in G_x
$$
and we are done.