# Using the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem to prove a set of matrices is a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, infinite-groups

I'm working on an unassessed course problem,

> Use the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem to show that the set of matrices $$
> M = \begin{pmatrix} 
> a&b \\ c&d 
> \end{pmatrix} 
> \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})
> $$
> with $a+c=b+d=1$ form a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I've written,

> Let $$G=\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}), \quad B=\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\ g&h\end{pmatrix}\in G, \quad A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}\in M;$$ clearly $G$ acts on $M$ by matrix multiplication and $$
> BA = \begin{pmatrix}e&f\\ g&h\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}ea+fc& eb+fd \\ ga+hc&ga+hd\end{pmatrix}.
> $$
> Now, clearly $\operatorname{orb}_G(A)=G$, and
> \begin{align}
> & \begin{aligned}[t]
> & (ea+fc)+(ga+hc) = (e+g)a+(f+h)c, \\
> & (eb+fd)+(ga+hd) = (e+g)b+(f+h)d
> \end{aligned} \\[0.5em]
> \therefore \; & \begin{aligned}[t] & \operatorname{stab}_G(A) = \{B\in G \text{ s.t. } e+g=f+h=1\}=M, \\[0.5em]
> \end{aligned}
> \end{align}
> so, by the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem, we have
> $$\infty = |\operatorname{orb}_G(A)| = \frac{|G|}{|\operatorname{stab}_G(A)|} = \frac{\infty}{\infty} \text{ or something.}$$

Is there a way to finish this argument validly?

Comment: The orbit-stabilizer theorem is no so much about cardinalities (which can be infinite), but about $G$-set isomorphisms $X\approx G/H$, where $H$ is the stabilizer of some point in $X$, and $G$ acts transitively. You can show directly that the stabilizer (and also pointwise-fixer) of _any_ group action is always a group.

Comment: @paulgarrett If I understand you right, to show that $M\leq G$ it's enough to show that $\text{stab}_G(A)=M\subseteq G$; but I don't see how that uses the OST. Any idea what the "Use the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem to show" instruction is getting at?

Comment: Unless there's some larger context... you do not need to invoke anything like the orbit-stabilizer theorem to understand that the subgroup fixing some set (on which the larger group acts) is a subgroup.

Comment: @paulgarrett OK, thanks. The comments are enough for me, but if you care to make it an answer I'll be happy to accept. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/265967/596895) contains a handy proof of the stabiliser-subgroup property you mention, in case anyone reading this finds it useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to use the orbit-stabilizer theorem, which is about a bijection between an orbit and the coset of a stabilizer of a point in that orbit, to prove that something is a (sub)group. However, perhaps the real intent here was to use that stabilizers of a group action are subgroups. With this, the proof is easy:

The group $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ from the right via
$$
(x\quad y) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 
a&b \\ c&d 
\end{pmatrix} 
= (ax+cy\quad bx+dy).
$$
Now the stabilizer of the vector $(1\quad 1)$ with respect to this action is the set of matrices you are considering.